# wordpress keeps looping to wp-admin.php on Nginx

Tags: wordpress, loops, nginx

I just installed a fresh instance of wordpress 3.5.1 from the latest.tar.gz file.

The installation dir is:

/home/wordpress

The DB access is ok. The site displays properly at the url doc.site.com

When I try to access through doc.site.com/wp-login.php and type in my admin credentials, wordpress keeps looping back to wp-login.php without any errors.

I'm using Nginx, Varnish on port 80 and php-fpm.

I'm not sure what's a rewrite rule that'd be proper. Also I verified the home and siteurl in the wordpress DB and the values are http://doc.site.com

Here is a copy of my "sites-available" file:

```
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name doc.site.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/doc.site.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx//doc.site.com.error.log;

        root /home/wordpress;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;


        # unless the request is for a valid file, send to bootstrap
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
        }

        # catch all
        error_page 404 /index.php;

        # use fastcgi for all php files
        location ~ \.php$
        {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
```

Comment: http://www.serverfault.com may be a better place to ask

Answer (score 0):

nginx should support Wordpress out of the box, with exception to short urls/slugs, which require a directive to be added to the site's `server` or `location` block.

The only difference between your setup and mine is that you use Varnish to accelerate your app. What happens if you try to turn it off?

What happens if you have the site listen on port 80?

Lastly, what does the error log at `/var/log/nginx//doc.site.com.error.log` say when you log in via `wp-admin.php`?

```
tail -F /var/log/nginx/doc.site.com.error.log
```